# Can FFMPEG pause a live audio recording when db levels fall below threshold?

Tags: audio, ffmpeg, live, recording

I am in the process of converting 100's of audio cassettes to FLAC files. I have used Audacity and RecordPad by NCH Software to set decibel (dB) thresholds. so that when my devices stop and require a tape flip, the recording also pauses.

I would like to move my tape playing devices (USB-based) to ubuntu 18.04 and run them on FFMPEG, but was wondering if FFMPEG had the ability to pause the recording when the audio signal falls below a configurable threshold.

This helps me reduce the storage waste. Soon I have to convert some older audio reels as well in which the problem will get worse.

The probe with Audacity is limited # of instances. If Audacity allowed me to instantiate multiple instances (1 for each playback device), I wouldn't be asking this question.

I'm a bit of a noob to shell scripting...here is the end of my current shell script:

`nohup ffmpeg -nostdin -f alsa -i hw:"$DEVICE" -t $DURATION  -filter:a volumedetect -ar 48000 -ac 2 -b:a 320k "$TITLE".flac 2> "$TITLE".log &`

Thanks in advance!

Deep

Comment: No such dedicated feature, but you may be able to output loudness/silencedetect metadata and issue SIGSTOP/SIGCONT.

Comment: sounds promising...i've updated my question to include my current ffmpeg command. How would I update it to do what you're suggesting? Thanks @llogan

Comment: Start with the [ametadata](https://ffmpeg.org/ffmpeg-filters.html#metadata_002c-ametadata) filter.